# My Asp.NET Web API POST function not work. Codes below

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

Two codes same function,Codes 1 work,Codes 2 not work.
Run Web API,Codes1 and Codes 2 has same curl.
curl -X 'POST'   'https://localhost:7147/api/xxxxx/xxxxxx'   -H 'accept: */*'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json'   -d '{
"id": 8259,
"data": "8259",
"toID": 0,
"fromID": 0,
"context": "string",
"timsStamp": "string"
}'

Codes 1:

```
    [HttpPost("{pass}")]//add
    public JsonResult Post(string pass, Dtable dta)
    {
        if (string.Equals(pass, Password))
        {
            string query = @"
                       insert into dbo.main
                       values (@ID,@Data,@ToID,@FromID,@Context,@TimeStamp)
                       ";

            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer");
            string Rmes = "Insert sucecss";
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", dta.ID);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", dta.Data);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToID", dta.ToID);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromID", dta.FromID);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Context", dta.Context);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", dta.TimsStamp);
                    try
                    {
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                    catch (System.Data.Common.DbException Exc)
                    {
                        Rmes = Exc.Message;
                    }
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(Rmes);
        }
        else return new JsonResult(null);
    }
```

This code work fine.

Codes 2:

```
    [HttpPost("{pass}")]//add
    public JsonResult Post(string pass, Dtable dta) //Dtable is Data Model
    {
        if (string.Equals(pass, Password))
        {
            string query = @"
                       insert into dbo.main
                       values (@DTA)
                       ";
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer");
            string Rmes = "Insert sucecss";
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTA", dta);
                    try
                    {
                        myCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                    catch (System.Data.Common.DbException Exc)
                    {
                        Rmes = Exc.Message;
                    }
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult(Rmes);
        }
        else return new JsonResult(null);
    }
```

These codes not work but no error message, I do'nt know why?

Comment: You should await ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

Comment: You need to explain `does not work`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/17302523/bgman: Modify two line.  async public Task<string> Post(string pass, Dtable dta) and await myCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTA", dta); -> this line error  Data Type not mapping. System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type ConsiderAPI.DataModel.Dtable to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Question is how to transfer Data Model to SQL query values(???)